# Lemma about transcendence basis

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero.

Let $R=k\big[z_1,...,z_p\big]$ a $k$-algebra of finite type which is a domain. Let $F$ be its field of fractions and $x_1,...,x_n$ a transcendence basis of $F$ over $k$ which verifies: $\forall i\in\{1,...,n\},\,x_i\in R$.

Show that $\forall j\in\{1,...,p\},\,z_j$ is algebraic over $k(x_1,...,x_n)$.

Can you help please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: you might start by reminding yourself of the definition of transcendence basis.

Comment: ok thanks i'm a total idiot ! I've been on it for like 4 hours